# setState() does not re-render from my code

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I gave onClick event for 3 items.
When I click the button, each button is going to call `clickHandler`
and `clickHandler` calls `changeSelect` with `event.target.id`.
In the function, I want to change `state` value by suing `this.setState()` and it works well.
But the problem is, after I call `this.setState()`, it does not trigger `render()`.
What is the problem with my code?

```
class About extends React.Component {
  state = {
    main: true,
    data1: false,
    data2: false
  };
  changeSelect = id => {
    if (id === "select1") {
      this.setState(current => {
        current.main = true;
        current.data1 = false;
        current.data2 = false;
      });
    } else if (id === "select2") {
      this.setState(current => {
        current.main = false;
        current.data1 = true;
        current.data2 = false;
      });
    } else if (id === "select3") {
      this.setState(current => {
        current.main = false;
        current.data1 = false;
        current.data2 = true;
      });
    }
  };
  clickHandler = event => {
    event.preventDefault();
    this.changeSelect(event.target.id);
  };
  render() {
    console.log('render called')
    console.log(this.state)
    return (
      <div>
        <section className="selects">
          <div
            id="select1"
            className="select"
            onClick={this.clickHandler}
          ></div>
          <div
            id="select2"
            className="select"
            onClick={this.clickHandler}
          ></div>
          <div
            id="select3"
            className="select"
            onClick={this.clickHandler}
          ></div>
        </section>
        <section className="about">
          {this.state.main ? (
            "hi"
          ) : this.state.data1 ? (
            "bye"
          ) : (
            "oh"
          )}
        </section>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: you should not mutate the state, calling setState with callback should return a modified state -> ```this.setState(current => ({
        main: true;
        data1: false;
        data2: false;
      });```

Comment: @ajaiJothi oh...I got it!! Thanks a lot!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Do not** mutate state -> return a  new one

```
changeSelect = id => {
  if (id === "select1") {
    this.setState(current => ({
      main: true,
      data1: false,
      data2: false,
    }));
  } else if (id === "select2") {
    this.setState(current => ({
      main: false,
      data1: true,
      data2: false,
    }));
  } else if (id === "select3") {
    this.setState(current => ({
      main: false,
      data1: false,
      data2:true,
    }));
  }
};
```

Note: if your *next* state doesn't depend on previous state value - you can omit function call and do it like that:

```
this.setState({
   main: false,
   data1: false,
   data2: true,
});
```

:)

Answer (score 0):

When you use this syntax on `setState` you need to `return` your new `state`:

```
//You are not returning your state just assigning the values
this.setState(current => {
        current.main = true;
        current.data1 = false;
        current.data2 = false;
      });
```

Just modify the state this way

```
this.setState({
        main:true,
        data1:false,
        data2:false,
      });
```

Comment: Don't know your earlier response, But you are correct, he wasn't returning also.

Answer (score 0):

After looking into the code. The issue is how `setState` is being used mutating the state won't re-render and instead return a new state.

Here is the ref:

```
if (id === "select1") {
    this.setState({
      main: true,
      data1: false,
      data2: false,
    });
}
```

Note: You are not making use of `current` so you can avoid the updater method of `setState`.

Answer (score 0):

As previously said by @max, You're mutating the state, and your setState isn't Returning anything,

Your set State

```
this.setState(current => {
        current.main = false;
        current.data1 = true;
        current.data2 = false;
      });
```

I would re-write your code like this to reduce conditions

```
state = {
    select1: true,
    select2: false,
    select3: false
};

const defaultState = {
  select1: false,
  select2: false,
  select3: false
}

changeSelect = id => {
    this.setState({ ...defaultState, [id]: true });
};
```

Answer (score 0):

1. You can use key for re-rendering component if key changes.
2. Use key as per your choice, i have used Math.random() for ex.

========================================================================

```
class App extends Component {
  state = {
    main: true,
    data1: false,
    data2: false,
    key:Math.random()
  };
changeSelect = id => {
    if (id === "select1") {
      this.setState(current => {
        current.main = true;
        current.data1 = false;
        current.data2 = false;
      });
    } else if (id === "select2") {
      this.setState(current => {
        current.main = false;
        current.data1 = true;
        current.data2 = false;
      });
    } else if (id === "select3") {
      this.setState(current => {
        current.main = false;
        current.data1 = false;
        current.data2 = true;
      });
    }
  this.setState({key:Math.random()})
  };

 render() {


    return (
      <div key={this.state.key}>
          {/*your code*/}
      </div>
    );
  }

}

export default App;
```